# NAnt stops working when I try to run it

Tags: c#, windows-8, nunit, nant

I am trying to convert my nunit xml tests to html but I cannot get NAnt running
When I try to launch NAnt manually I get this right away followed by a Nant stopped working pop up:

The First Type of permission failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

I get a similar result when I try to start it's proccess in c# which I need to do in the end.

I made a build file from this website and I also tried their steps manually: http://ajeeshvl.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/converting-nunit-xml-test-result-to-html-formatc-seleniumrc-nunit-framework/

I tried moving the build file to the same folder as NAnt.exe and in the downloaded nunit2report file but that didnt make it work either.

It's very confusing to use NAnt and I still can not find Nunit2Report console exe(if there is one) and I've been trying to find clearer steps online.

My NAnt version is 0.92
And I am using Windows 8 as my OS

Thank you

Comment: Are you running from a shared network drive? There are some issues with running NAnt or NUnit from a network location, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you right click on the downloaded zip file for NAnt and unblock it. Then extract it and try. This was the issue I got on Windows 7.

Nunit2Report console exe is a part of nantcontrib. You will have to download it.
http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you, I could not find it from the files I was downloading before. This exe makes things a lot easier

Comment: Do let me know how it goes. We had issues with NUnit2Report. It was messing up with the number of Errors and Failures.